# C# MonoTouch/Xamarin - Built In Camera Button

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, camera, xamarin

I know there are some built in button images like "add"(which gives you a plus) and "edit"(which says edit).

Is there one for a camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera

[Apple's HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41) lists all of the available system buttons

Answer (score 0):

I found this site that has a nice big list of all the drawables you can use from Android.
[Click](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/)

Comment: It's nice but the question is about iOS (MonoTouch tag).

Comment: Oh my bad, need to pay more attention to that.